# How to Create automatic Main menu.lst and other sub menu.lst for Grub4Dos depending on the Component selections

Tags: inno-setup

I have my inno-setup program ( " Multboot Usb for Win&Linux " ) working perfect. The problem I have is that I have to write all Menu.lst files required for a particular Entry manually after installation. I would like to have a script that will create all menu.lst files automatically during installation depending on the selected Components. Hope am clear, and if not please let me know!

Thanks!

ANY HELP PLEASE....!!!!

Comment: Yes, that should be possible, I think. Just the structure of that menu file is more complicated for writing a generic function. Anyway, are you going to append menu items to an existing menu.lst file, or just generate a brand new file ? I'm asking because the first would require parsing of the existing file.

Comment: Thanks TLama for your response! I want just to generate new menu files as the component selected so that to leave those unselected items behind, i mean they should not be included in either of those menu  files. .

Comment: Hey TLama! Is there any alternative to this approach? Please let me  know if any, thanks!